# Can I download extension from my existing opencart website

Tags: opencart

Sorry if my question is not good.

**Question :** I install revolution slider extension in my opencart website. Now I need that slider in an other website of opencart. Can I download that slider extension from my existing website.

**Note :** In simply I mean, 
I want to export extension from one website and import it into another website..

Comment: Why not? Both are your sites!! What's the issue that you're facing now?

Comment: I want to export extension from one website and import into another website..

Comment: You've bought the extension. So what's blocking you from importing it to another site?

Comment: I don't know how can I import this.

Comment: Don't you have the `revolution slider` extension download link ? If yes, plz download and import to your new site.

Comment: there is no such thing like exporting an extension in opencart. extensions are installed by placing certain files to different directories (generally just vqmod directory). most extensions ships in zip containing all files and instructions to install. so if you don't have zip of that extension you will have to manually identify which files belongs to that extensions and place those files in respective folders of your other opencart site

Comment: Please, make sure, that the license of the extension is allowing You to use one copy (one purchase) on more/unlimited sites. This always depends on the developer of the extension. If this is not allowed by the license, You should buy additional license and install this to Your next shop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have purchased the extension the first thing you need to do is check your license agreement that you can use the extension on multiple sites. If you can, then the next thing you will need to know is where all the files are for that extension and copy them from one site to the other. If you have the original extension you can just upload that, but if you don't you will have to search for files containing a keyword of the extension. In your case, I would recommend searching for "revolution" to find all the necessary files. Chances are there's no easy way to export this, as most extensions span multiple files and folders

Comment: I purchase the extension but at this time I don't fond this extension in my system I think it deleted from my system. But I know where I use it. Now I want to import this extension from that website where I use it.

Comment: If it's from the opencart store, you can just download it again after you log in. If it's not, you need to contact the owners site with your details and they'll most likely check and give you the download